# How to export Graph with Annotations from Google Analytics

Tags: graph, google-analytics, export

Is it possible to export a Site Usage graph with annotated events dates from Google Analytics say, into MS-Word?

I know how to do screen shot capture to my image editor, but I was hoping to do something a bit more automated or streamlined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this website. You need GreaseMonkey and Firefox. And a bit of patience ;)

http://damionbrown.com/2012/02/export-and-share-google-analytics-annotations/